# Pointer to array as function parameter

Tags: c, pointers

I wrote a function which takes a pointer to an array to initialize its values:

```
#define FIXED_SIZE 256
int Foo(int *pArray[FIXED_SIZE])
{
/*...*/
}

//Call:

int array[FIXED_SIZE];
Foo(&array);
```

And it doesn't compile:

> > error C2664: 'Foo' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int (*__w64 )[256]' to 'int *[]'

However, I hacked this together:

```
typedef int FixedArray[FIXED_SIZE];
int Foo(FixedArray *pArray)
{
/*...*/
}

//Call:

FixedArray array;
Foo(&array);
```

And it works. What am I missing in the first definition? I thought the two would be equivalent...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
int Foo(int *pArray[FIXED_SIZE])
{
/*...*/
}
```

In the first case, **`pArray` is an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array**.

You need parentheses to use a pointer to an array:

```
int Foo(int (*pArray)[FIXED_SIZE])
```

You get this for free with the `typedef` (since it's already a type, the `*` has a different meaning). Put differently, the `typedef` sort of comes with its own parentheses.

Note: experience shows that in 99% of the cases where someone uses a pointer to an array, **they could and should actually just use a pointer to the first element**.

Comment: Yep, pointer to first element as well as the size (if needed, which it probably is).

Answer (score 1):

One simple thing is to remember the clockwise-spiral rule which can be found at 
http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

That would evaluate the first one to be an array of pointers . The second is pointer to array of fixed size.

Answer (score -1):

An array decays to a pointer. So, it works in the second case. While in the first case, the function parameter is an array of pointers but not a pointer to integer pointing to the first element in the sequence.